# predict_proba(X) of RandomForestClassifier (sklearn) seems to be static?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, probability, random-forest

For all classes I want to retrieve the prediction-score/probability of a given sample. I'm using the RandomForestClassifier of sklearn. My code is running fine if I'm using `.predict()`. However to show the probabilites I'm using `.predict_proba(X)` and it returns always the same values, even then when `X` changes. Why is that so and how to fix it?

I'm breaking down my code to the concerning parts:

```
# ... code ... feature generation / gets the feature data
if rf is None:
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=80)
    rf.fit(featureData, classes)
else:
    prediction = rf.predict(featureData) # gets the right class / always different
    proba = rf.predict_proba(featureData) 
    print proba # this prints always the same values for all my 40 classes
```

Interestingly `max(proba)` retrieves the class that `.predict()` returns in the very first run. Due to `.predict()` is working as expected I believe the error is at sklearn's side, i.e. I guess there is a flag that needs to be set.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is you are passing always the same argument to `predict_proba`. Here is my code to build a forest of trees from the iris dataset:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=80)
rf.fit(X, y)
```

When I call the methods `predict` and `predict_proba`, the class and class log-probability predictions for different arguments are also different, as one could reasonably expect.

Sample run:

```
In [82]: a, b = X[:3], X[-3:]

In [83]: a
Out[83]: 
array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2]])

In [84]: b
Out[84]: 
array([[ 6.5,  3. ,  5.2,  2. ],
       [ 6.2,  3.4,  5.4,  2.3],
       [ 5.9,  3. ,  5.1,  1.8]])

In [85]: rf.predict(a)
Out[85]: array([0, 0, 0])

In [86]: rf.predict(b)
Out[86]: array([2, 2, 2])

In [87]: rf.predict_proba(a)
Out[87]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])

In [88]: rf.predict_proba(b)
Out[88]: 
array([[ 0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.0125,  0.9875],
       [ 0.    ,  0.0375,  0.9625]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your time there was some kind of loading error for `X`. However I'm still wondering why `predict()` worked out. Thank you that helped me a lot